# Get Folder NTFS ACL on long path name

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I have a PS script that will return NTFS ACLs if an individual user is assigned, works well until I hit a path exceeding 260 characters. I've found a lot of information on the path too long problem and some work-arounds but I'm struggling to integrate a solution into my script. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

```
$DateStart = Get-Date  
$Path = "E:\"           
$PermittedOU1 = "OU=Groups,dc=chiba,dc=localt"
$PermittedOU3 = "OU=System Accounts,OU=Accounts,dc=chiba,dc=local"
$PermittedACL1 = get-adgroup -Filter * -SearchBase $PermittedOU1 
$PermittedACL3 = get-aduser  -Filter * -SearchBase $PermittedOU3
$ObjectPathItem = Get-ChildItem -path $Path -Recurse | where-object {$_.PsIsContainer} | foreach-    object -process { $_.FullName } 
$howmany=0  
$Logfilename = "C:\Users\administrator\Documents\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm).csv"


Add-Content $Logfilename "$DateStart`n"
$totalfolders=0
$i=0

ForEach ($Folder in $ObjectPathItem)
{
$totalfolders++
}



Foreach ($Folder in $ObjectPathItem)                                                
{                                                                            

   $ObjectACL = Get-ACL -Path $Folder                                            
   $i++
   $howmany=0 
   Write-Progress -id 1 -Activity "Folder Recursion" -status "Folders Traversed: "                 -PercentComplete (($i / $totalfolders) * 100)


   Foreach ($ACL in $ObjectACL.access)                                       
    {

        $ACLstring = $ACL.identityreference.Value                           
        $ACLstring = $ACLstring.Replace("CHIBA\","")                        
        if (($ACLstring -notin $PermittedACL1.name)`
        -and ($ACLstring -notin $PermittedACL3.SamAccountName)`
        -and ($ACLstring -notin "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM") `
        -and ($ACLstring -notin "BUILTIN\Administrators") `
        -and ($ACLstring -notin "CREATOR OWNER"))   
         {
                 $newline = "`"$Folder`"" + "," + "$ACLString"
                 Add-Content $Logfilename "$newline"   
                 $howmany+=1 
            }

        else {
                $howmany+=1
             }

    }


}
$DateEnd = Get-Date
Add-Content $Logfilename "`n`n$DateEnd"
```

Comment: You could probably catch that exception(when you hit the long path) with the problematic path and use part of that path (less than 260 chars) and map it as a new-psdrive and proceed with the ACL application. This is just the suggestion, I don't have the code ready.

Comment: Since Windows 10 there's a [registry setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later) for long path support in .NET applications (like PowerShell) that you could try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you can usually use is to create a mapped drive using New-PSDrive. Something like:

```
Try{
    $ObjectACL = Get-ACL -Path $Folder
}
Catch{
    $SubPathLength = $Folder.FullName.substring(0,200).LastIndexOf('\')
    $NewTempPath = $Folder.FullName.SubString(0,$SubPathLength)
    New-PSDrive -Name Temp4ACL -Provider FileSystem -Root $NewTempPath
    $ObjectACL = Get-ACL "Temp4ACL:$($Folder.FullName.SubSTring($SubPathLength,$Folder.FullName.Length-$SubPathLength))"
}
```

That will find the last `\` before the 200th character in the path, grab a substring of the full path up to the end of that folder's name and create a temp drive of it, then get the ACL based off the temp drive and the remaining path. So this path:

```
C:\Temp\Subfolder\Really Long Folder Name\Another Subfolder\ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\We Are Really Pushing It Now\Im Running Out Of Folder Name Ideas\Hello My Name Is Inigo Montoya\You Killed My Father Prepare To Die\ReadMe.txt
```

Gets cut at the second to last backslash. I would end up getting the ACL from:

```
Temp4ACL:\You Killed My Father Prepare To Die\ReadMe.txt
```

Comment: good idea but it's still throwing the same error:                 Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.                                                         the try and catch seem to not be happening during the get-childitem?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not realize that you were getting that error on the Get-ChildItem. That does make sense, but is going to be harder to work on since you can't just pick up where you left off. You could do a Try/Catch on the Get-ChildItem with a similar theory, but it really doesn't come out very well with the inability to pick up on the -Recurse where you left off when it errors.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is to use "\\?" to support 32,767 characters.

```
$folder = "C:\MyFolder"
icacls "\\?\$folder"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx

In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode version of the function (GetFullPathNameW), and prepend "\\?\" to the path.

Comment: It's unfortunate get-acl seems to not accept \\?\. I get an empty result when running your example

Comment: So your suggestion is to edit the source code of `icacls` to call `GetFullPathNameW` and re-compile it? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this question is quite old but for those coming here as of today like myself I provide this information that I found through Google:

Microsoft Technet Script Center lists a "[File System Security PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85)" which claims that since version 3.0 it "leverages the AlphaFS (http://alphafs.codeplex.com) to **work around the MAX_PATH limitation of 260 characters**". At the time of this writing the module is at version 4.2.3.

The general idea of this module is described as "PowerShell only offers Get-Acl and Set-Acl but everything in between getting and setting the ACL is missing. This module closes the gap."
So without having tried this myself I suppose it should help in solving the OPs problem.

The module is also featured in a post by the "[Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/22/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-add-and-remove-ntfs-permissions/)".