# Getting ACL info using PowerShell and Robocopy due to PathTooLongException

Tags: windows, powershell, acl, robocopy

I'm trying to get a listing of all permissions on some network folders using PowerShell. Unfortunately I'm encountering the dreaded PathTooLongException so I'm attempting to use Robocopy as a work around. However I'm a complete novice with PowerShell so was hoping for a little help. The easiest command I've come up with is

```
Get-Childitem "S:\StartingDir" -recurse | Get-Acl | Select-Object path,accestostring | Export-Csv "C:\export.csv"
```

That works and does what I want except the exception I'm getting. How would I insert Robocopy into this statement to bypass the exception? Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `Get-ChildItem "\\?\S:\StartingDir"` ?  I don't know whether PowerShell will work with long paths, but it would be worth trying.

Comment: I had come across that "\\?\" clause before but trying it doesn't seem to work at all. The script doesn't even run when I add it.

Comment: I've been playing with this, and you can get the long filenames with Robocopy with `$files = robocopy c:\temp NULL /L /S /NJH /NJS /NDL /NS /NC`, then loop through them with `foreach($file in $files){`.  However, `Get-Acl` doesn't handle the long names, so it still doesn't work.  Also tried cacls.exe--also doesn't work with long paths.  I tried the method at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805419/get-folder-ntfs-acl-on-long-path-name to map a PSDrive, but I couldn't get that to work with Get-ACL either.  If you have a manageable number of places where this occurs, you can use shares.

Comment: I sort of thought Get-Acl wouldn't work but I thought I'd see if anyone else knew better than I. Thanks for the help and the info.

Comment: I even tried a method using a batch file to return the short filename, and the run Get-Acl with the short name, but that doesn't work either.  Get-Acl is getting the long path of the file regardless of whether a short path or a PSDrive path is passed to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a batch file, such as getShortFilename.bat, with the following lines:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo %~s1
```

This will return the short filename of the long filename passed to it.  The following script will use that to get the short filename when Get-Acl fails due to a long path.  It will then use the short path with cacls to return the permissions.

```
$files = robocopy c:\temp NULL /L /S /NJH /NJS /NDL /NS /NC
remove-item "c:\temp\acls.txt" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach($file in $files){

    $filename = $file.Trim()
    # Skip any blank lines
    if($filename -eq ""){ continue }

    Try{
        Get-Acl "$filename" -ErrorAction Stop| Select-Object path, accesstostring | Export-Csv "C:\temp\acls.txt" -Append
    }
    Catch{
        $shortName = &C:\temp\getShortFilename.bat "$filename"
        $acls = &cacls $shortName 
        $acls = $acls -split '[\r\n]'
        #create an object to hold the filename and ACLs so that export-csv will work with it
        $outObject = new-object PSObject
        [string]$aclString

        $firstPass = $true

        # Loop through the lines of the cacls.exe output
        foreach($acl in $acls){

        $trimmedAcl = $acl.Trim()

        # Skip any blank lines
        if($trimmedAcl -eq "" ){continue}

            #The first entry has the filename and an ACL, so requires extra processing
            if($firstPass -eq $true){
                $firstPass = $false

                # Add the long filename to the $exportArray
                $outObject | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "path" -Value "$filename"

                #$acl
                # Add the first ACL to $aclString
                $firstSpace = $trimmedAcl.IndexOf(" ") + 1
                $aclString = $trimmedAcl.Substring($firstSpace, $trimmedAcl.Length - $firstSpace)

            } else {
                $aclString += " :: $trimmedAcl"
            }
        }

        $outObject | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "accesstostring" -Value "$aclString"
        $outObject | Export-Csv "C:\temp\acls.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The string of ACLs that is created by Get-Acl is different from the on created by cacls, so whether that's an issue or not...
- If you want the ACL string to be in the same format for all files, you could just use cacls on all files, not just the ones with long filenames.  It wouldn't be very difficult to modify this script accordingly.
- You may want to add extra error checking.  Get-Acl could of course fail for any number of reasons, and you may or may not want to run the catch block if it fails for some reason other than the path too long.

Comment: Thanks very much for coming up with a solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help!  I gave up yesterday but apparently just needed to sleep on it.